# Browser based controller for Java game

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, socket.io

I have a fairly simple game written in Java. For a project, I want to have the game up on a big screen and have people connect their smartphones/tablets to it as a controller so they can compete against each other.

I do not want people to have to download/install anything to join in, so I thought a browser based solution would be the best solution. I'd have a small website running locally that people within the network can access and have an interface there for controlling the game.

I thought this would be easy using websockets but as it turns out Android stock browser does not support them.

I also tried socket.io, but the demo I installed also does not work on my Android phone.

Is there any other technique/software I can try? Or maybe some examples which do something similar? How would you approach this? Should I look into php for this?

To specify what I need. Some browser based system that:

- Does not require anything to install on client side
- Works on almost all stock mobile browsers
- Sends simple messages over upd or tcp

If it makes anything easier, the game is running on the same machine as the website. The game is a standalone java application using java swing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also note, that you might run into problems with chrome since they stopped supporting an applet.

Comment: Starting with Android 4.4, there is no stock browser anymore. The Web view component has been switched to Chrome for Android - and this does support WebSocket, so web socket would be the best approach

Comment: @FredericHenri I'm a little afraid that a lot of people who will attend have older smartphones. So if there is any other approach, it is at least worth a try. If there's no easy alternative, I will use WebSocket.